# Delete certificate from MS certificate store with Java and SunMSCAPI

Tags: java, certificate

I'm trying to delete a certificate from Windows' "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store. This store can be accessed from java using the `SunMSCAPI` provider and according to [oracle's documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) one should be able to read and write to the "Personal" store and the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". At least that is my interpretation of the sentence

> In addition, changes are reflected immediately when making modifications to the keystore, such as KeyStore.setKeyEntry(...), KeyStore.deleteEntry(...).

However, when trying to delete an entry I get a `java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.`

My code looks like

```
final KeyStore msCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
msCertStore.load(null, null);
if (msCertStore.containsAlias(mCertificateName))
{
  getLogger().info("Removing certificate with alias '{}' from store '{}'", mCertificateName,
      mCertificateStore.getStoreName());
  msCertStore.deleteEntry(mCertificateName);
}
```

and what I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: Access is denied.

    at sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.removeCertificate(Native Method)
    at sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.engineDeleteEntry(KeyStore.java:542)
    at sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore$ROOT.engineDeleteEntry(KeyStore.java:68)
    at java.security.KeyStore.deleteEntry(Unknown Source)
    at my.playground.DeleteCertificateCommand.execute(DeleteCertificateInstallerCommand.java:67)
    ...
```

The user account that is used to execute the code is local administrator and I can manually delete the certificate from the store in Windows' certmgr.msc GUI. But it won't work using the above code.

Removing a certificate from the Personal store `Windows-MY` works, seems to be related to access rights though. But what rights would I need?

BTW: Operating system is Windows Server 2008 RC2

Comment: In Windows since Vista userid being "administrator" isn't always enough, some things need the specific process to be **elevated** as well, apparently to slightly reduce the number of people hit by driveby downloads that pwn their system silently. I know on my Vista and Seven certmgr prompts for elevation. There are many ways to elevate but as a simple test if this is console mode (java not javaw) try rightclick CMD RunAsAdministrator (even though you are already logged in, I know) then your java under that.

Comment: I put the command line to execute in a bat-file and chose "Right-Click -> Run as Administrator" -> Same result: Access denied

I execute the command in Windows command prompt using runas to run the command under the local Adminstrator accoung -> Same result: Access denied

Actually I'm not asked to execute certmgr.msc with elevated rights when opening it using the "normal" domain account...

BTW: Operating System is Windows Server 2008 RC2

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Do you have any update about this issue?

Comment: @Moez not really. There doesn’t seem to be any pure Java solution for this problem. I solved my requirement by calling `certutil.exe` using `ProcessBuilder`. For other more sophisticated certificate store related issues I used `jPowerShell` with some ps1 scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html

```
// Note: When a security manager is installed, 
// the following call requires SecurityPermission 
// "authProvider.SunMSCAPI".
ks.load(null, null);
```

Comment: There is no security manager in place and the failing operation is not the loading of the store but the call to `sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.removeCertificate` (see above stacktrace).

However I put the operation inside a `PriviledgedAction` and executed it using `AccessController.doPrivileged`, but the result remains the same...